# Add to LINQ Include Expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression

I am writing a function that allows a user to get a queryable list of devices from the database (the underlying provider is EF).  But I want to allow them to specify their own includes, but if they do always include the default include of `Capabilites` how do I do this?

```
public IQueryable<Device> GetAllDevices(params Expression<Func<Device, object>>[] includes)
{
    // I really want to do something like includes.Add(d => d.Capabilities)
    // (I know the above code wouldnt work, but illustrates what I want)

    var newIncludes = includes /*(and somehow)*/ d => d.Capabilities, 
    return this.Repository.GetAll(newIncludes);
}
```

This is the function used on my repository class that aggregates the includes sent in which works. I just can't seem to figure out how to add a single default include into the above function

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = this.dbset;
    if (includes != null)
    {
        query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
    }

    return query;
}
```

Comment: No... I want to ensure that Capabilities is included in the returned results as well as any extra includes the user specifies

Comment: Does the repository fetches all the records from database before returning them, or it just gets an IQueryable from EF and returns it?

Comment: IQueryable and returns it.  Ive updated my Repository code to show how GetAll works.  `GetAll()` works fine, I just cant figure out how to, in my `GetAllDevices` function to add a default include to any the user passes in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific limitation in not using the same [`Include()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696450(v=vs.103).aspx) twice. The second one is ignored.

```
public IQueryable<Device> GetAllDevices(params Expression<Func<Device, object>>[] includes)
{
    return this.Repository.GetAll(includes).Include(x => x.Capabilities);
}
```

This will always `Include(x => x.Capabilities)`.

Your question isn't clear... perhaps if the user doesn't include anything (`includes` is empty), you don't want to include `Capabilities`:

```
public IQueryable<Device> GetAllDevices(params Expression<Func<Device, object>>[] includes)
{
    IQueryable<Device> query = this.Repository.GetAll(includes);

    if (includes != null && includes.Length != 0)
    {
        query = query.Include(x => x.Capabilities);
    }

    return query;
}
```

Comment: This won't work given my current structure will it? .Include doesn't exist on IQueryable does it?

Comment: @Chris in `System.Data.Entity` there is an extension method `Include`. It is the same that is being used in the `GetAll()`

Answer (score 0):

You can chain "Include().Include()..." like:

```
(IQueryable<T>).Include("Something").Include("SomethingElse");
```

You could use that and a loop on the "includes" array inise your function like:.

```
IQueryable<T> example = (some IQueryable<T>).Include(Capabilities);
foreach (include in includes)
    example.Include(include);
```

Answer (score -1):

return DbSet
                .Where(Your Condition)
                .Include(string.Join(".", include))
                .FirstOrDefault();